# Can 't deploy webhook

Tags: webhooks, dialogflow-es

Everytime if I want to export my webhook into my firebase project this happens:

- functions: Finished running predeploy script.
  i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
- functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
  i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
- Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/Nameoftheproject-d9d5/overview

It says that the deploy is complete, but it doesn't create a function or export my webhook in my firebase project. I want to export all to a webhook so I can use it in my dialogflow project. Can someone help me out? I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code that you're trying to deploy?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do the following

You need to enable Webhook in your Dialogflow fulfillment and paste the deployment URL of Firebase functions that are deployed using `firebase deploy`.

Like this:
[image: Dialogflow fulfillment]

Make sure you are using the correct Actions Project before firing `firebase deploy`

```
firebase use <PROJECT_ID>
```

Your Action's project ID can be found in the Actions Console, under Overview > (Gear icon) > Project settings.

Refer the following Google Codelabs link to setup connection between your local environment and firebase functions:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/#2